# Show hide multiple divs on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html-table, show-hide

I have to show opened works (1, 2, 3...) in tables including a list of related tasks (1, 2, 3...), each one in a row. The tasks may be opened or closed. I try to find a way to hide/show the closed tasks (rows) for a specific work (table) by clicking on an element like the line in class "showhideforwork-x".

```
<table class="work-1">
  <tr class="showhideforwork-1"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Task 1 (opened)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-1"><td>Task 2 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-1"><td>Task 3 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Task 4 (opened)</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="work-2">
  <tr class="showhideforwork-2"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-2"><td>Task 1 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-2"><td>Task 1 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Task 3 (opened)</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="work-n">
  <tr class="showhideforwork-3"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Task 1 (opened)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-n"><td>Task 2 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-n"><td>Task 3 (closed)</td></tr>
</table>
```

I think I don't use the classes the way it should be to catch the click on "showhideforwork-x" elements and hide/show the corresponding "showhidework-x" rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a common class to the closed elements, find all elements with that class inside the parent and hide/show (toggle) them

HTML

```
<table class="work-1">
  <tr class="showhideforwork"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Task 1 (opened)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-closed"><td>Task 2 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-closed"><td>Task 3 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Task 4 (opened)</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="work-2">
  <tr class="showhideforwork"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-closed"><td>Task 1 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-closed"><td>Task 1 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Task 3 (opened)</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="work-n">
  <tr class="showhideforwork"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Task 1 (opened)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-closed"><td>Task 2 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-closed"><td>Task 3 (closed)</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(".showhideforwork").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".showhidework-closed").toggle();
});
```

Edit:
Fiddle
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w3x19of1/)

Comment: You are right, instead of hiding should toggle() instead. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you @Janar! Yes, it works fine. I am not used to the parent() statement.

Answer (score 0):

I did this. Is this what you need?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkTasks(){
    var check = $('tr td');
    console.log(check[1]);
    $('tr td').each(function(index) {
    //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
      if( $( this ).text().indexOf("closed") != -1){
   $(this).parent().hide();
  }
    });
  }
  checkTasks(); 
  //you can call this function on body load or set 
  //time out to check every 5 or 10 minutes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="work-1">
  <tr class="showhideforwork-1"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Task 1 (opened)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-1"><td>Task 2 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-1"><td>Task 3 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Task 4 (opened)</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="work-2">
  <tr class="showhideforwork-2"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-2"><td>Task 1 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-2"><td>Task 1 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Task 3 (opened)</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="work-n">
  <tr class="showhideforwork-3"><td>Hide closed tasks</td><tr>
  <tr><td>Task 1 (opened)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-n"><td>Task 2 (closed)</td></tr>
  <tr class="showhidework-n"><td>Task 3 (closed)</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure it will do the job. The answer of @Janar works fine.

Comment: Agreed on that.

Comment: If Janar's answer worked for you, why don't you accept it?